# Touch control hob (electric stove)

Tags: button

I have a hob with the touch button but not responding enough. It's a Fujistu Siemens.
The touch buttons are cover by aluminium case.

[image]

In the image above that is touch button. If I can say is a touch button, because only when the plate is pressed by any object the hob responds. I try to activate a button with my finger and it works but sometimes it does not work at all.

[image]

How can I just put normal switches or make the touch more sensitive? The buttons are powered by a pic16f886.

P.S. Can someone tell me what the heck is this? it is on every button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a capacitive switch, and the IC is a combination of amplifier and flip-flop (or scr) circuit that works with the capacitor.  If you can provide the wiring diagram, I should be able to tell you if a "regular" switch can be used to replace them.

It now appears that the switches are the contact type. I would recommend first to clean the contact surfaces of the switches with alcohol and lint free cloth. If this does not make them work better, then use a momentary push button switch by connecting it across the corresponding contacts.  However, making space for each micro switch might become a problem.  You might want to replace only those that are giving you problems.

Comment: i will try to draw a schematic. thx for the reply

Comment: Hi. here is the schematic.sorry for the horrible writeing. hope it helps me somehow.![](http://i58.tinypic.com/2yo674n.jpg)